# ContentObserver for SQLite database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, observer-pattern, contentobserver

I've got an android app with an SQLite database, and I'm wondering how to create and register a `ContentObserver` that will be notified of changes to the database. I know that I could do this using a `ContentProvider`, but I am only using the database for my app, so there's no need to make it into a `ContentProvider`, and I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing in Java (before 1.7) like the WatchService for watching a directory?

Comment: Just create a content provider, it is very straightforward

Answer (score 6):

`ContentObserver` only works with a `ContentProvider`.

What it sounds you want is an event bus, whereby the code of yours that alters the database can post an event, and the code of yours that is interested in such changes can listen for the event. Basically, you use the event bus as the communications layer for your observer pattern. The "big three" options here are:

- `LocalBroadcastManager` from the Android Support package
- [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
- [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Comment: afaik ContentObserver are genaral purpose beasts

Comment: @pskink: Not really. You could shoehorn `ContentObserver` into roles other than for working with a `ContentProvider`, ignoring the `Uri` and such, but it does not gain you anything over using something other than `ContentObserver`. The only place *Android* uses `ContentObserver` is with a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: i'd say that ContentResolver is the main place where android uses ContentObservers so using CR API the OP could achieve what they want

Comment: @pskink: You are welcome to provide a working example where a `ContentResolver` accesses a `SQLiteDatabase` without a `ContentProvider`.